# Return Single or Double Quotes to Javascripts Func

Tags: javascript, asp.net, eval

I'm doing a little function whereby when user click on a linkButton on the GridView, the data from the gridview will bring to the javascripts function for some purpose. Well, everything works fine except when Single or Double Quote appear in the data(Msg). I try to use the Replace function on the `Eval("Msg")`, but it doesnt allow me to do so. Any ideal?

My Code Snippet:

```
<scripts>

     function MyJFunc(Msg) {
        alert(Msg);
    }

</scripts>

<ItemTemplate>
    <a onclick='<%# String.Format("javascript:MyJFunc(""{0}"");", Eval("Msg"))%>' href="javascript:void(0);">Show Message</a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use escape function.

I your case: use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`

```
<a onclick='<%# String.Format("javascript:MyJFunc(""{0}"");", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Msg")))%>' href="javascript:void(0);">Show Message</a>
```

Comment: i tried, not working...Do i need to include any other JS file in my project?

Comment: What is not working? do you get any error?
It's server-side code.
It's replacing unique html characters.
see an example over here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx)

Comment: remain the same, Eval("Msg") couldn't pass to the function MyJFunc();